# android static layout error

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, system-error

I just installed **CatLog** on my **Alcatel onetouch pop c2** and I saw there is many weird errors.

**Error:** StaticLayout: length=52;   index=53.

I don't know what is that but I got many of them.

Anyone know how to fix it?

**OS:** Android 4.2.2 JellyBean (build 01002) (Model number 4032D)
**RAM:** 512MB
**Kernel version:** 3.4.5

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Are you observing a perceivable issue on your device or have you asked this out of curiosity?

Comment: @Firelord curiosity, and i cant see other errors (messages)

Comment: Is your device rooted? If not, you should ask the CatLog author. Reason: With Android 4.2+ apps only get to see their own logcat messages (to see other apps' messages requires root then), so these errors must be caused by the app itself.

Comment: Seems a similar issue with [this on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849676/i-cant-figure-the-issue-with-a-stacktrace-error)... the `length=52; index=53` is really a hint of `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException `, but not sure why it's shown as `StaticLayout`. [Related issue #35412 on AOSP](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35412)

Comment: @Izzy its rooted